# Create a JUnit for Camel route and processor

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, apache-camel

I am new to JUnit. I am trying to write test case for camel route and processor. I don't know how to start. Here is my route

```
from("activemq:queue1").process("queueprocessor").toD("activemq:queue2").
```

I need help to mock my endpoints and processor.

Comment: Sorry, this is not enough information to give a usable answer. Check out the different [Camel testing flavours](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/testing.html). Depending on the "environment" your Camel routes lives in, the route test will be completely different. For example in a SpringBoot project you can enable Camel route test features with annotations, in a plain Camel test you would extend a Camel class.

Answer (score 0):

Here mocked all endpoints using "isMockEndpoints" & added expected body content to endpoint(activemq:queue2) and by sending same content as input to mocked endpoint(activemq: queue1) verified assert is satisfied or not.

```
public class MockEndpointsJUnit4Test extends CamelTestSupport {

 @Override
public String isMockEndpoints() {
    // override this method and return the pattern for which endpoints to mock.
    // use * to indicate all
    return "*";
}

@Test
public void testMockAllEndpoints() throws Exception {
    // notice we have automatic mocked all endpoints and the name of the endpoints is "mock:uri"
    getMockEndpoint("mock:activemq:queue2").expectedMessageCount(1);
    getMockEndpoint("mock:activemq:queue2").expectedBodiesReceived("Hello World");

    template.sendBody("mock:activemq:queue1", "Hello World");

    getMockEndpoint("mock:activemq:queue2").assertIsSatisfied();
    /* additional test to ensure correct endpoints in registry */

    /* all the endpoints was mocked */
    assertNotNull(context.hasEndpoint("mock:activemq:queue1"));
    assertNotNull(context.hasEndpoint("mock:activemq:queue2"));
 }



}
```

Comment: You probably want to assert `mock:activemq:queue2` (not `queue1`) since you haven't defined expectations on `mock:activemq:queue1` and don't assert `mock:activemq:queue2`

Comment: Yes, you are correct @burki ..Replaced (mock:activemq:queue1)   with correct one (mock:activemq:queue2)